# Why did Jon Snow want to join the Night’s Watch?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Early in the book and the show we hear of Jon’s determination to join the Night’s Watch. However, most people seem to regard the brothers as a bunch of thieves, scum, and rapists.

However, it seems to be all Jon wants. Did he come to this decision by himself or was he encouraged by Ned so that

> He would give up his birthright and no longer be a threat to King Robert.

I wonder because Ned tells him they’d talk about his mother once he’s said his vows. Obviously this never happened.

Did Jon come to his own decision to joint the Night’s Watch or did Ned plant the idea in his mind to keep him safe?

Comment: The rank and file (emphasis on the rankness) are the scum of the earth. Jon, on the other hand is a highly trained soldier with extensive knowledge of tactics and logistics. Someone of his calibre would expect to join (or easily become) an officer.

Comment: and in the North joining the Watch is consider honourable act.

Comment: The duplicate covers all the reasons someone would join and Aegon's excellent answer covers Jon specifically.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot However, the questions are different, and there is no accepted answer on the "duplicate." To make this a duplicate is to decide that the answer for the other question answers this one - and, in essence, to force the OP to accept an answer of a post that has no accepted answer. This may have still been fine if the two questions were identical, but they are not.

Comment: @MishaR whether or not an answer is accepted has no bearing on whether it is a duplicate or not. Also this question is a subset of the other question ___and___ is answered on the duplicate.

Comment: Ned did not encourage Jon, on the contrary he was actually more inclined to forbid it until Maester Luwin and Catelyn pressurised him. His promise to talk about Jon's mother only happened in the show. Jon had decided to join the watch solely because he saw how bastards were treated, was aware that all his siblings had their future secure for them and knew that NW would be his chance to rise high in the world, his only chance. Of course he was a bit naive and believed that the bedtime stories about heroic NW men were real and that all NW men were like his uncle Benjen. Tyrion opened his eyes